# Is the series of this sequence $U_{n}$ convergent

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Is the series of this sequence $U_{n}$ convergent

$U_{n}=\left (\cos \left ( \frac{1}{n} \right )  \right )^{n^{3}}$

should i go with this method ?

$$V_{n}=\sqrt[n]{U_{n}}\\
W_{n}=\sqrt[n]{V_{n}}\\
Z_{n}=\sqrt[n]{W_{n}}\\
Z_{n}=\sqrt[n^{3}]{U_{n}}$$
then i use Cauchy critera ?

Comment: Not a very promising approach. Do you know the Taylor series for cosine at $0$?

Comment: Hmm not the slightest idea

Comment: Do you mean the sum of the  series, that is, you mean to ask whether (the sum of all the terms up to $n=m$ converges as $m\to\infty$?.

Answer (score 0):

You may use root test: This is because note that for sufficienlt large $n$, $\cos (\frac{1}{n})>0$ and hence $\lvert U_n\rvert ^{\frac{1}{n}
}=(\cos (\frac{1}{n}))^{n^2}$ and hence $\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}\lvert U_n\rvert ^{\frac{1}{n}}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\lvert U_n\rvert ^{\frac{1}{n}
}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(\cos (\frac{1}{n}))^{n^2}=e^{-\frac{1}{2}}<1$. Hence the series converges absolutely.

Comment: how did you find this result : $e^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ from  $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(\cos (\frac{1}{n}))^{n^2}=e^{-\frac{1}{2}}<1$

Comment: Yes, but the root test would fail to show that $\sum(\cos(1/n))^{n^{3/2}}$ also converges absolutely.  In fact, the series converges with the key exponent as small as $\frac{19}{8}$ and even a bit smaller.

Comment: Ayman Erroutabi, please see this link, and use f(x)=cos(1/n), g(x)=1 and h(x)=n^2,   http://www.vitutor.com/calculus/limits/one_infinity.html

Answer (score 0):

Actually there was a similar question asked few days back and answered by Ted some days back too,

Also it would be helpful if you can cite some reference from where you faced the question :)

So the Approach is to check with the sequence term $U_{n} = (\cos(\frac{1}{n}))^{n^{3}}$ of the series,

Taking $\log$ we get $\log(U_{n}) = (n^{3})\log(\cos{\frac{1}{n}}) = (n^3)\log(1 - \frac{1}{2n^{2}} + \frac{1}{24n^4} - ... ) \approx (n^3)(-\frac{1}{2n^2})$

So as $n \rightarrow \infty$, $U_{n} \rightarrow 0$ thus the series converges!

Comment: how is $\log(1 - \frac{1}{2n^{2}} + \frac{1}{24n^4} - ... ) \approx (-\frac{1}{2n^2})$ ?and about the reference it's a bunch of exercices handwritten by our university's teacher can't be more precised than that xD

Comment: $\log(1-x+\frac{x^2}{6} - ...) \approx -x $ when $x \rightarrow 0$.May be here https://www.desmos.com/calculator/fyqkmi4qkl @AymanErroutabi , Ok I thought it appeared in some exam like for consecutive days I saw the same type of questions a lot.